# multiple java servers and batch programs - XML configuration nightmare

Tags: java, xml, configuration

I have an application that consists of approx. 20 java components.
About half of the components are servers and the other half batch programs.
Almost all of them talk directly to an oracle database (jdbc via some of our infrastructure code jars) the other couple of components talk to some of the servers which talk to the database.
Anyway, each component is configured with numerous XML configuration files.
These are becoming almost impossible to maintain.
Some of the configuration is specific to a component others are similar (database URLs, connectors etc)

What is worse is that the application is not installed in many environments - in fact only about 10 environments (qa, dev, production etc etc).
But the people who own these environments don't seem able to maintain the configs correctly.
In particular whenever there is an upgrade there is invariably configuration errors.
I have even started checking in some of the environments configurations into SVN along with the code.
I tried an xml schema validator at one point (it consisted of defining the valid XML in .xsd files and then throwing an error if the schema rules were breached but that didnt work)

I'm thinking I am missing something basic here - perhaps there is a tool to manage this or perhaps I should be storing the configuration in the database.
The application was largely designed by a colleague but I feel myself that it's overly configurable - in fact many of the config actually refers to classes - i.e. one can choose handlers and parsers etc - the XML config almost looks like code.
Any advice greatly appreciated
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting XML for code is usually a bad idea; things that are declarative are probably OK, but things that are procedural probably aren't.

If all that configuration was defined in Java code, a lot of the upgrade issues would turn into compilation issues. The compiler would pick them out for you, and you could correct them.

So you've got a multi-part problem. You need to rationalize your configuration information into a set of partitions (per-component, per-installation, global). You need to try to verify configuration information at compile-time, where possible. And you need to write validation for the loaded configurations, to sanity check them.

To the extent possible, shift configuration relatively static stuff into Guice (at least, it's what I prefer). A lot of things happen in a nice, type-safe way with it.

Consider running a WebDAV server for each instance of the app, and storing configuration into it. Each can hit a simple URL to pull the current versions of the configuration files.

Or, stand up a lightweight XML database like BaseX with its REST capability, then store and load your configuration information there. Use JSLP or something like it to have your components find the central configuration repository.

An additional advantage to using an XML DB is that you'll be able to do a lot of sanity checking and updating by querying across the set of all configuration files. For example, if a given instance of the application should have the same JDBC parameters in each configuration file, a simple xquery will tell you if that's true.

If you don't have the ability to modify the applications that are pulling the configuration file (the config file format is fixed), then consider writing a query servlets for the XML database that *assemble* the required configuration information, from nested blocks or templates. That will allow you to figure out what's common between the configuration files and dynamically generate parameterized versions of those blocks.

Sounds like the key here is making incremental improvements. Allow the old way to configure, but have the configuration load *look* for a central config source first.

Comment: Thoughtful response. Yes there are Global / per environment / per component configurations. I guess the Global stuff that never ever changes should probably be packaged in a jar instead of leaving it there in a file. I wonder if storing the XML configuration in the Oracle database is a runner. http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10790/xdb03usg.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the syntax of the configuration files is at the heart of the problem: using Java properties files instead of XML would leave you with exactly the same issues. There may be an issue that the configuration information is too dispersed - it's hard to tell. The main issue seems to be that the whole thing is too fragile - the application is too dependent on manual configuration, and it seems that the configuration for each environment needs to be different. You should try to focus on reducing the number of configuration parameters that need to be set to make the system work (without necessarily reducing the options available for diagnostics etc for use when they are really needed.), on having intelligent defaults and self-configuration. Perhaps even invest in creating an installation wizard.

Answer (score 0):

As you have some Oracle databases handy why not store your configuration in there?

Then you only need one or two configuration parameters to point to an Oracle database suitable for that environment and download the rest of the configuration from the database.

The contents of the configuration table should be pretty static for any given environment so there should be no need to amend anything except the jdbc connection when you migrate your software through its life cycle.